# How do I move folders within multiple directories up one level recursively?

Tags: directory, mv

I have a 'All_Subjects' folder, and within it many differently named subjects, e.g.
4000ab, 4001er, 4002fd, 4003hg etc.

Then within each individual subject I have the same folder structure, i.e. task/level_one.
e.g.  All_Subjects/4000ab/task/level_one

Please, how do I move, for each subject, the level_one folder up one level to be in the individual subjects' folder, e.g. All_Subjects/4000ab/level_one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: mv All_Subjects/4000ab/task/level_one All_Subjects/4000ab/level_one?

Comment: Yes but how do I do that for each subject in the 'All_Subjects' folder, without having to type the individual subject ID (e.g. 4001er, 4002fd, 4003hg) each time?

Comment: use the find command and take action on each folder that matches.